# R calling a function on several instances of the same reference class object

Tags: r, class, dynamic, reference

I have a reference class (myRefClass) and have created several instances of this say ref1, ref2 ref3

```
ref1<- myRefClass()  
ref2<- myRefClass()  
ref3<- myRefClass()
```

I am struggling to iterate through the instances (ref1, ref2 and ref3) and call a class function.

I can do:

```
ref1$say_hello()
ref2$say_hello()
ref3$say_hello()
```

But if I put either the objects or names in a list, how can I iterate through them and call the function say_hello on each member of the list?

```
listOfObjects <- list(ref1, ref2, ref3)
listOfNames <- list("ref1", "ref2", "ref3")

# iterate through list and call say_hello() neeeded
```

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

I have now managed this using get:

```
names <- list("ref1", "ref2", "ref3")
for(ref in names){
  get(ref)$say_hello()
  }
```